# Does the stage keyword define a Build or Deploy pipeline in Azure DevOps in YAML file

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml

I would like to know if if we consider this block of YAML code if this is already considered a Build and Release pipeline...or we need to define stages to characterise that. This below code  works but you don't see the individual stages when you run this. However it does Build and Deploy to Azure in this case. So that's why I ask. I am looking for correct terminology. Is this a Build and Release pipeline or you can't say that and only if I define the stages Build and Release it is one.

Hope this is clear.

```
  # ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: 'drop'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 
    packageForLinux: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/*.zip'
```

Answer (score 0):

In YAML, there's no distinction. A pipeline is a pipeline. If it contains stuff that results in software being released, feel free to call it a release pipeline if you want.

Comment: So Daniel what you are saying I can easily call this a Build and Release pipeline and it wouldn't matter ? Meaning it would still be correct?

Comment: Sure. A pipeline is a pipeline. Whether it's a **good idea** to combine build and release into a single job versus breaking it out into multiple stages (or even multiple pipelines) is a different discussion that's entirely dependent on your goals and requirements.